# PHP if/else conditionals

Tags: php, conditional-statements

I'm using Perch CMS and I'd like to try and  minimise the number of templates I've used.

I'd like to be able to show and hide sidebar content depending on which page is being viewed.

Let's say my sidebar has three modules:

```
Module-A
Module-B
Module-C
```

and I have three pages

```
/home
/about
/blog
```

I think I need to write a 'else if' statement, how would I write the following in PHP?

If on **home page** show Module-A
If on **about page** show Module-B
If on **any other** page show all Modules

Comment: Did you do a google search on conditionals and php?  That might be a good start.

Comment: Yes, but I know hardly anything about PHP - it seems a bit tricky. I've used conditional statements within WordPress templates, but I'm unable to write 'pure' PHP. Thought I'd give stackoverflow a try.

Comment: You should really try to learn PHP before working with CMS. Trust me, everything will be easy once you know the basics.

Comment: Yes, I think it would help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know that a lot of little and easy to use CMS are free and open source ?

I don't know how you must include your modules, but to filter you can use `switch` (better than `elseif`)

```
switch($page){
  case '/home':
  include(Module-A);
  break;

  case '/about':
  include(Module-B);
  break;

  case '/blog':
  include(Module-C);
  break;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I really like Perch, I'm happy to pay a small licence fee for a great product. 'switch' looks interesting. How could I inject HTML into the include()? could I use include(snippet.html);

Comment: Yes, exactly. "include(snippet.html);" will search the snippet.html file and insert it's content. Don't forget to provide the filepath, if snippet.html is in the template folder, your include will be "include(template/snippet.html);"

Comment: Hmmm, what does this bit mean 'switch($page)'? I've looked on http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_switch.asp and 'switch' looks like what I need. but I can't get it to work...

Comment: $page is the variable which contains /home, /about or /blog. switch() will check it's value, and execute the corresponding function. If $page is /home, case: '/home' is triggered and the Module-A is included.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a proper answer, as I don't know how Perch works, but this should give you the general idea of how conditional statements work.

```
$page = ''; // Page name here, I don't know how you set that in Perch

if($page == 'home_page'){
    echo $modulea;
}elseif($page == 'about'){
    echo $moduleb;
}else{
    echo $modulea . $moduleb . $modulec;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply! How would I add HTML into the 'echo'?

Comment: You can put it in a separate file and include(module.html); or just bung it straight in the echo like: echo "module html here";

Answer (score 0):

```
currentpage->assign('basename',basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI']));
```

then do if statements based on the contents of that string, however your page is set up

Comment: I'm a PHP noob. This has gone right over my head :) Any chance you could explain it a bit more?

Comment: So that there will get you a string for part of the url, you can do some string comparison conditionals on that string to set up your if-else blocks.  I can help you with those if you tell me the urls, or if you run that line of code on each of the 3 pages